# Keep surface 'dry' in fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

Is there a way in Blender to set some surfaces to be wet or dry for fluid simulation? I want to make a drop of fluid wrap around some object with a wet surface, but not spread around on a dry surface. Is it possible in Blender 2.72? If yes, how can I make this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make the surfaces the fluid hits look wet?

Comment: I think he wants a drop to stick on a dry surface and slip freely on a wet surface. That would be the slip type and amount available in domain and obstacle fluid types.

Comment: I want to make "wet" area surrounded by "dry" area. Then I put a drop of fluid to "wet" area and it should stay at this area, it should not go to "dry" area.
I try to use obstacles with "no slip" and "free slip" parameters but this only affects the gap between fluid and surface...

Comment: What about making an invisible fluid obstacle object around the dry areas?

Comment: Hmm, just the gap between the surfaces.. I'm no expert with fluid simulation, but did you try increasing the resolution of the fluids?